# Python Auto it Control click not working

Tags: python-3.4, autoit

```
autoit.control_click("Digital Oscilloscope", "", "[CLASS:ScrollToolbar; INSTANCE:1]", "Left", "1", 295, 11)
```

When I execute this I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       autoit.control_click("Digital Oscilloscope", "", "[CLASS:ScrollToolbar; INSTANCE:1]", "Left", "1", 295, 11)   File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyautoit-0.4-py3.4.egg\autoit\autoit.py",
>   line 73, in wrapper
>       ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
>
> **TypeError: control_click() takes 2 positional arguments but 7 were given**

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2):

Working after defining the **Kwargs explicitly

```
autoit.control_click("Digital Oscilloscope", "", "[CLASS:ScrollToolbar; INSTANCE:1]",click=1,x=95,y=11)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have given too many arguments to the `control_click()` function, you only need 2 parameters: ClassID and ControlID.

Look here for an example: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoIt/0.3

Comment: Thanks. In that case how can we use cordinates in control_click